# Showing Activity after Dropbox Authentication

Tags: android, authentication, dropbox

I am developing an application with multiple activities. I am using Dropbox to access files. 
I used dropbox apis as per tutorial given.
In the tutorial it is written that : ***"Upon authentication, users are returned to the activity from which they came. To finish authentication after the user returns to your app, you'll need to put the following code in your onResume function."***

However, in my case, after authentication default launcher activity is shown. It is not showing the activity from where the Dropbox authentication is initiated.

Code for initiating authentication is:

```
mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(context);
```

Any help ?

Comment: if not too long, show Your activity code from the one which should appear and the one which does appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. There are 2 activities in my app lets say **Activity A** and **Activity B** .I am starting **Activity B** from **Activity A** and initiating dropbox authentication from **Activity B**.After completing dropbox authentication, **Activity A** was shown and not **Activity B**. So to solve this problem,I killed **Activity A** after starting **Activity B**.

This is work around for the problem but not a solution. Hope it helps.